# How to fix an infinite recursive folder?

Tags: directory, directory-structure

I have an SD card with images in folders. Formatted as ExFAT.
Somehow, the directory contains a loop: in this case, folder 100RECNX contains itself *ad infinitum*
I am guessing the folder references back to itself. I havent a clue how to fix this. Is it possible to fix this directory?
[enter image description here][1]

**Edit:**  I hope to salvage the images in the folder.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aTsbe.png

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO. This is probably a better question on [www.superuser.com](http://www.superuser.com), which is more about solving system issues. StackOverflow is about programming.

Nevertheless, copy files out, reformat?

Comment: Thank you Macke. I will look over there, didn't realise such questions were less fitting in SO. 
Problem is I cannot 'reach' the files, as the folder only contains itself.